# Изменить прослушиваемый адрес приложения

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Есть asp.net mvc приложение, запускаемое на localhost. Для тестов нужна связь с внешним миром - был проброшен порт на роутере для этого:

```
192.168.0.204:1234
```

Извне в приложение стучатся, например, по адресу

```
http://localhost:35843/test
```

Можно ли изменить прослушиваемый приложение адрес с localhost:35843 на 192.168.0.204:1234? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В appplicationhost.config необходимо в секции проекта изменить или добавить строку:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1234:192.168.0.204" />
```